# How to allow special characters like the dash in Java Application?

Tags: java, spring

**How to allow special characters like the dash in Java Application?**

This issue is when user Copy and Paste the value from a Word Document then System shows “?” instead of dash “–” character. The copy String has dash char instead of the hyphen. Em dash and hyphen (En dash) are different characters and Em dash character is not a part of ASCII character. Its character code is \u2014. My Application does not support the dash character.

**Example 1:- Not Working: Input String: "Anil – Satija" and Display Value: "Anil ? Satija"**
**Example 2: Name= "Anil - Satija" - hyphen is working fine and shows correct value.**

Client-side technologies are Angular 1.5.5 and Server-side technologies are Spring5.2.2. Sending the request as POST. The application supports charset "UTF-8" and content-type is "application/xml". I tried to add the below code in API also to accept the all UTF-8 character set.
**index.html Meta Data :**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

**API Code is:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @Consumes("application/xml; charset=utf-8")
  public @ResponseBody
                String getData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Throwable {
                    RequestPayLoad requestPayLoad = parseRequest(request);    
         // requestPayLoad has corrupted value.
        // code
 }
```

In debug, at the Client layer (xFactory.js) $scope.data has the correct value with dash but API layer (HttpRequest) request has the corrupted character. So, the System displays the '?' for the corrupted character in this case.

Comment: Character encoding can go wrong on many levels. I do not believe there is anything wrong with the data; the problem seems to be in the displaying side. It might be as simple as the used font not supporting this particular unicode glyph.

Comment: How do you print the value to verify it's wrong on the server? The character you show is not the ASCII dash (-), but the En Dash U+2013. If you just print it to `System.out` then it's quite possible that your console simply can't display it (as that's often configured to some basic ISO-8859-* variant) and that would lead to it being replaced with `?`. Try iterating `yourString.codePoints().forEach(System.out::println)`. If that doesn't print `63` anywhere (which would be the code for `?`), then the `String` is correct and it's the displaying that's the problem (it should then contain 8211).

Comment: @Gimby: slight correction: if the *font* is the problem, then you'll see a square instead of the character (sometimes with hex digits inside), or in some bad cases nothing. If it displays `?` instead of the character, then the issue is almost certainly encoding-based.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ha! I was under the impression that this was simply a difference in default behavior between different tools/platforms. There is always something new to learn about character encoding.

Comment: @Gimby: funnily enough there actually is a Unicode character for "I can't decode this to a valid Unicode character", which is U+FFFD and is usually rendered as an inverted question mark in a rotated, filled square (�). However when the problem happens when converting from a fully Unicode-capable encoding to a less capable encoding then that usually can't be used, so it's often replaced with a boring old ASCII "?" (at least that's the default behaviour in Java and I think also for `iconv`)